# List Capacity Property increasing unexpectedly.. why?

Tags: c#, list

I create a List of say, Customer objects, with an initial size of 0.

```
List<Customer> firstCustomerList = new List<Customer>();
```

Outputted Capacity property of the List is 0.

I add one Customer to the List..

```
firstCustomerList.Add(customer1);
```

Now, the outputted Capacity property of the List is 4.

The Customer object is indeed just a single object, is not another List. More so to the point, if I add 3 Customer objects, then apply the TrimExcess() method to the List, it does reduce the List to the correct size.

So why does it bump up the Capacity of the List to 4 with just the addition of a single object?

Comment: So in essence, it allocates memory ahead of time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Capacity` is the size of the array that is actually holding the data. `Count` is the number of elements in the list.
Adding an element to an array is cheap - as long as your array is large enough. As a list does not know how large it will be, it has to resize the array dynamically, to the `Capacity` size. That is expensive (you have to copy every element), and therefore it will allocate more than it needs, to limit resizing operations.

Comment: So what does the array hold, if not just the 1 object?

Comment: A list with count 1 and capacity 4 has: an backing array with size 4(=`Capacity`), which is empty except for the one element you added, and an int pointer telling the list where to write the next element into the array.